# C++ templates weird behaviour: "not matching function" outside main

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, matching

I am working with templates which I am not very familiar with but something weird is happening. I have a templated class which inherits from other templated classes.

The problem is that when I create an instance of the class in the main method it works as expected. However, when I create the very same instance inside a function then it throws compilation error: "not matching function" pointing to the constructor of the templated class.

The question is why does it work in the main method but not inside a function the very same piece of code (there is no problem with inclusion)

The code is huge but I ll try to illustrate with an example

```
int main() {
MyTemplatedClassParent<parameters> example(arguments);

MyTemplatedClassChild<parameters> example_1(arguments);
}
```

Works perfectly fine. However

```
int main() {
myMethod();
}
```

with

```
myMethod() {
MyTemplatedClassParent<parameters> example(arguments);
MyTemplatedClassChild<parameters> example_1(arguments);
}
```

does not. Basically in the second case it does not recognize the match between the call and the constructor of the class and it suggests as a candidate the constructor of the class I want to use. The point is that the very same thing works in the main method the only difference is that in the second case it is declared inside a method.

### edit:

Ok, somehow the problem was on the parameters of the templates that were the default ones originally. I know almost nothing on templates, but it appears that there were inconsistencies between the parameters of the two instances that were arising when the method was called. Do not know how and why, but as soon as I specified explicitly the parameters of the templates it compiled and worked fine. Again sorry for not giving much information but my knowledge on templates is very limited.

Comment: Why don't you show the declaration of the class  + its constructor? We're not psychic :)

Comment: You should try to create a minimal compilable example that reproduces the error you are getting. We cannot help you from the code you have given us.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, I ll try. But It ll take a while sonce it has multiple inheritances. But the weird thing is that it works perfectly fine in the main method. Nothing should change. But you are right I ll try to illustrate better but It ll take time.

Comment: @Altober: actually, the minimal example is not only for us, by shaving off what is unnecessary to reproduce the problem, it may very well appear to you :)

Comment: Are `arguments` visible from `myMethod`?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yeah you are right is just that it will take long. But I ll do it. I was expecting something like there is a known bug or something like that.

Comment: @jcalvosa Yes, I am passing the arguments manually.

Comment: @Altober: ugggh. **[select isn't broken](http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips)** all over again :) It happens hundreds of times per day on SO. Unlearn it!

Comment: @sehe Yes, most of the times.. and also it does not consider psychological effects over sudden changes over the deadline ;-)

Comment: Are `myMethod` and `main` defined in the same file? What is `myMethod`'s return value?

Comment: @AntonioPerez Thanks Antonio somehow is solved see edit above.